# Fitting/Painting text to a shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, typography

I'm trying to make an effect of text that looks similar to this artful style (http://orkposters.com/product/boston-neighborhood-18-x-24-classic-black-white-poster/) while fitting it within a custom shape.

Is there a widget or package that can fit text to a custom shape? I saw that there is BoxFit and you can fit images to fill an area. Is this possible with text?

I'm not sure if there's any known algorithm for painting text this way that I could use as a starting point.